# Selenium WebDriver Session

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm a newbie here learning :P Probably a very basic question but I just don't know how to ask or search for it.

So I decided to make a crawler for a webpage in java using selenium, and I noticed if I do not terminate the session fast enough than it freezes =( So does that mean I have to call .quit() often and keep opening new WebDriver? Or is there a way to continually interact with the website?

Like for example: I wish to open up Google. Type "pie" and click search, maybe I didn't like the result and wish to search for "apple pie" and keep doing that for extended period of time?

Comment: YOu can do it for extended period of time, but you will have to change the script lil bit manually to achieve this.

Comment: It was just an example, I wish to continually use the driver for different tasks

Comment: What browser is it? What version of that Browser?

Comment: What are you terminating the session for? Calling `quit()` is an unusual thing to do with webdriver; you rarely need it in normal use.

Answer (score 1):

This is I what I had done for my playtime practice. YOu can make use of it.

```
String[] location = new String[] { 
                                   "Los Angeles", 
                                   "Santa Barbara",
                                   "San Jose" 
                                 };

 // Some code 

@Test
public void testSelServerDiceTest() throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < location.length; i++) { // manually added for loop
        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.type("id=FREE_TEXT", "selenium RC JUnit");
        selenium.type("id=WHERE", location[i].concat(" CA"));
        selenium.click("xpath=//*[@id=\"searchSubmit\"]");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Search results:"));
        verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Search job title only"));
        verifyEquals("JUnit", selenium.getText("css=div.undoLabel"));
        verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("selenium"));
        verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Search results: 1 - 1 of 1"));
        assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Search results:"));
    }
}
//Some more code
```

**EDIT**

```
// webdriver code snippet

@Test
public void testRemoteWebDriverDiceTest() throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < location.length; i++) {
        driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
        driver.findElement(By.id("FREE_TEXT")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("FREE_TEXT"))
                .sendKeys("selenium RC JUnit");
        driver.findElement(By.id("WHERE")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("WHERE")).sendKeys(
                location[i].concat(" CA"));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"searchSubmit\"]")).click();

        try {
            assertEquals("JUnit",
                    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.undoLabel"))
                            .getText());
        } catch (Error e) {
            verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is that older version of Selenium? I thought they use WebDriver class now. I wish to know how to prevent the memory leak if I do not terminate the driver?

Comment: Sorry for posting `selenium` instead of `webdriver`, anyhow base concept remains same. About memory leak you can see [here](http://selenium.10932.n7.nabble.com/WebDriver-and-IE9-memory-leak-td22307.html)